# Create a dublicate of swift files

Tags: ios, xcode

I've finally released my free iOS application. Right now I'm working on to create my next version which is going to be a paid one.

So the paid app should be exactly the same but with a lot more functions etc. And therefor I wanna copy my iOS project map and create a duplicate of it and start programming the premium version but I don't know how I can do this.

So my question is: How can I copy the other project and add it into a new one and add more stuff to it? I do not wanna lose anything on the other one.

Any good tips on this?

Comment: You only want one app in the store, not two. So no need to create a new project.

Comment: Why? @rmaddy  lol

Comment: Because Apple will want you to only have one version of your app, not two. They won't want you to have both a free version and a paid version. They will want you to have one version. You will want that one version to start off free and have in-app purchase to allow the user to upgrade to the full version.

Comment: @rmaddy i’ve seen a lot of apps with 2 versions tho, hmmm

Comment: I had an app with two versions in the store for over 9 years. Then one day last year Apple refused to let me update them until I consolidated down to one. So yes, there are existing free/paid pairs. But they are cracking down on the practice. It's actually a lot simpler to have just one app to maintain and it's far less confusing for users.

Answer (score 0):

Just add two Build Targets to Xcode, one for the paid version and one for the free one.

And the files that stay the same than choose both targets for the file.
Files that only apply to one target can also be added to one target only.

If one file/Class is different in each version, than you could either have a base class/file wich applies to both, and for each Version a file with an extension to the class or just duplicate the file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy the entire folder in Finder. Change what you want it in the 2nd, keep the free version in the original folder.